# Dom Traversal Complex Table Layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, tree-traversal

I a have a webpage with a complex table structure. The entire code is right here --> (index.php)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
    // this turns the json object into an array
    $json_string = file_get_contents("info.json");
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  ?>

  <div id="scroll_box">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" id="container">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="organizer">

            <?php foreach($json as $key => $value): ?>

              <!-- this is what needs to be repeated -->
              <tr><td class="index"> <?php echo $key ?> </td></tr>
                <thead class="sticky" align="center"><tr><th> <?php echo $value["name"] ?></th></tr></thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="spell_container">

                        <?php
                          foreach ($value["items"] as $key => $value) {
                            echo '<tr><td><table class="table-bordered spell_shorthand">'.
                                  '<tr><td>Name</td><td class="name">'.$value["name"].'</td></tr>'.
                                  '<tr><td>Type</td><td class="type">'.$value["type"].'</td></tr>'.
                                '</table>'.
                              '</td>'.
                              '<td class="description">'.$value["description"].'</td>'.
                              '<td><div class="btn-group"><button class="learn">Learn</button></div></td>'.
                            '</tr>';
                          }
                        ?>    

                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".learn").on('click', function(){

      var the_name = $(this).closest("tr").find("table.spell_shorthand").find("td.name").text();
      var the_type = $(this).closest("tr").find("table.spell_shorthand").find("td.type").text();
      var the_description = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.description").text();
      var the_index = $(this).closest("table.organizer").find("td.index").text();

      console.log(the_name);
      console.log(the_type);
      console.log(the_description);
      console.log(the_index);


    });
  </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

and the JSON data that is being used looks like this --> (info.json)

```
[
    {
        "name": "level0",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item1",
                "type": "type1",
                "description": "this is item 1"
            },
            {
                "name": "item2",
                "type": "type2",
                "description": "this is item 2"
            },
            {
                "name": "item2",
                "type": "type2",
                "description": "this is item 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Level1",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item4",
                "type": "type4",
                "description": "this is item 4"
            },
            {
                "name": "item5",
                "type": "type5",
                "description": "this is item 5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Level2",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "item6",
                "type": "type6",
                "description": "this is item 6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now. All of my console.log statements in the js script work perfectly except for the one that deals with "the_index" ... for whatever reason, it is returning all of the instances of index (0, 1, 2) when really it should just be returning the index of the header that is the parent of the button that is clicked.

I encourage you to take these two files and see for yourself what I'm talking about.

Any insight as to why clicking a button under the first index (0) would return (0 1 2) would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: My guess is you are grabbing all the td.index you want the closest. Have you considered indexing the master rows (the parent) in your loop? you can then add a data attribute to your buttons. onclick you get the data attribute which can be your master row id and pretty much easily access anything inside there without much trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running an index on your tables in the loop like so:

```
<?php
  $num_row = 0;
  foreach ($value["items"] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr id="row_'.$num_row.'"><td><table class="table-bordered spell_shorthand">'.
    '<tr><td>Name</td><td class="name">'.$value["name"].'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><td>Type</td><td class="type">'.$value["type"].'</td></tr>'.
    '</table>'.
    '</td>'.
    '<td class="description">'.$value["description"].'</td>'.
    '<td><div class="btn-group"><button class="learn" data-row-id="#row_'.$num_row.'">Learn</button></div></td>'.
    '</tr>';
    $num_row = $num_row + 1;
  }
?>
```

You can revise your click event to be something like below using jQuery. This will simplify things quite a bit.

```
$(".learn").on('click', function(){
  var row_selector = $(this).data('row-id');
  var the_name = $(row_selector + ' .name').text();
  var the_type = $(row_selector + ' .type').text();
  var the_description = $(row_selector + ' .description').text();
  var the_index = $(row_selector + ' .index').text();
});
```

Comment: Oops... you need that count on the master row wrapping the entire table. I'm going to revise that code!